# sort and filter product with query builder spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have  filter product that have sort and filter
sorting by price, created at , available product
But when I filter the product, I can no longer sort the same product filter
for example
[http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?&filter[brand]=1](http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?&filter%5Bbrand%5D=1)
and I want sort product in brand based on created at but
When I click on the latest, the link does not continue the filter and only does the sort
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product?sort=created_at
I know there is a problem with my JavaScript, but I do not know how to solve it

```
<form method="GET" id="jobfilter-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="product-short">
        <ul class="products-archive-tabs watch-page">
            <p>order by ::</p>
          
            <li>
                <a id="createdAt" href="{{ URL::current()."?sort=created_at" }}">
                    The oldest
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="createdAt" href="{{ URL::current()."?sort=-created_at" }}">
                    the newest
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="shop-box-area">
    <div class="sidebar-categores-box shop-sidebar mb-10">
        <div class="expander">
            <div class="inner-bit">
                <ul class="barnd-item">
                    @foreach ($brand as $brands)
                        <li>
                            <label class="m-checkbox">
                                <input
                                    name="brand" type="checkbox" value="{{ $brands->id }}"
                                    @if (in_array($brands->id, explode(',', request()- 
                                   >input('filter.brand'))))
                                    checked
                                    @endif
                                >
                                {{ $brands->name }}
                                <span class="count-brand">({{count($brands->product)}})
                                                                    number
                                                           </span>
                                <img src="/photo/brandsmall/{{$brands->smallbarnd}}">
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

java script

```
  <script>
    function getIds(checkboxName) {
        let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName(checkboxName);
        let ids = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkBoxes)
            .filter(ch => ch.checked == true).map(ch => ch.value);
        return ids;
    }
    function filterResults() {
     
     
        let brandIds = getIds("brand");
        let createdAt = getIds("createdAt");
     
        let href = 'product?';

       
        if (createdAt.length) {
            href += '&sort[created_at]=' + createdAt;
        }

     
        if (brandIds.length) {
            href += '&filter[brand]=' + brandIds;
        }

        document.location.href = href;
    }

    $("#jobfilter-form #filter").on("click", e => {
        filterResults();
    });
</script>

 $products = QueryBuilder::for(Product::class)
        ->allowedFilters([
            AllowedFilter::exact('brand', 'brand_id'),
        ])
        ->allowedSorts('created_at')
        ->defaultSort('available_id')

        ->with('category')->paginate('5')
        ->appends(request()->query());
```

How can I keep the latest value in the link?

Answer (score 0):

At First, you should not have duplicated ID value in your elements.
`id="createdAt"` is duplicated.

Second, you are using `href` for the sort function, whenever you click on it, the page will redirect to the URL of the `href`. so other things on the page will reset.

You should use a checkbox for sort items without the `<a>` tag, then when `filter results` are called, your sort items will be added to the URL without any page redirection.

Comment: can you give an example for me?